# Why does HTMLEditorKit not want to insert <i> element inside a <b> element?

Tags: java, html, swing

The full source can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JGgithub2018/4b36c98817a4e98fdec06872cfe56d2a).

## How to reproduce in the source:

1. Run the program
2. Click the bold button
3. Type something
4. Go somewhere inside the bold text
5. Click the italics button
6. Type more stuff
7. Note how the italicized text is not bold.

## MCVE:

Here you go. Mostly generated by Eclipse, so it's quite long.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        JEditorPane editPane = new JEditorPane();
        editPane.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(editPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        HTMLEditorKit HTMLKit = new HTMLEditorKit();

        StyleSheet css = HTMLKit.getStyleSheet();
        css.addRule("body {font-family: Helvetica;}");
        HTMLKit.setDefaultCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));

        editPane.setEditorKit(HTMLKit);
        editPane.setOpaque(true);
        editPane.setText("<b>I \"WHAT?\"</b>");
        
        JButton btnInsertTheText = new JButton("Insert the text");
        btnInsertTheText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    HTMLKit.insertHTML((HTMLDocument) editPane.getDocument(), 3, "<i>SAID ", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.I);
                }
                catch (BadLocationException | IOException exc) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                //System.out.println(editPane.getCaretPosition());
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnInsertTheText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Run the example, and click the button.

The desired output is: **I *SAID* "WHAT?"**

Actual output is: **I** *SAID* **"WHAT?"**

This is for a text editor that I am building with support for formatting.

So what's going on right now is that if I try to insert an `<i>` tag into a `<b>` tag, it inserts the `<i>` tag. The result? The `<b>` tag is either moved out of the way or split up! How do I insert one into the other?

Comment: *since I need user input,* - no you don't need user input. Your question is about using a method. So first you test the method with hard coded data. Once that works then you modify your code to use dynamic data. Post a proper [mre] in the forum.

Comment: Hey there @camickr, I added an MCVE

Comment: Good MRE. (except for a few unrelated lines of code - like the style sheet logic). Unfortunately I have never had much luck doing anything fancy with HTML. Instead I usually use a JTextPane and use "attributes" to style the text. I do have a solution that appears to work using a JTextPane with HTML, but I can't paste the code since the question was closed (due to a lack of MRE when you first posted the question). So I suggest you create a new question with the above MRE  and then I can post my suggestion there. You should then delete this question.

Comment: @camickr Just as a heads up, The question has been re-openend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a JTextPane to display HTML.

I find it easier as you can then use text attributes to mark up the text and you don't need to worry about HTML tags.

Adding the text becomes a two statement process:

1. you first insert the text so it inherits the attributes currently in effect at the insertion position
2. you then apply the "italic" attribute to the newly added text.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class TextPaneMRE extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                TextPaneMRE frame = new TextPaneMRE();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TextPaneMRE()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
        textPane.setText("<b>I WHAT?</b>");
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        SimpleAttributeSet italic = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setItalic(italic, true);

        JButton btnInsertTheText = new JButton("Insert the text");
        btnInsertTheText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    StyledEditorKit editorKit = (StyledEditorKit)textPane.getEditorKit();
                    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument();
                    String text = "SAID ";
                    doc.insertString(3, text, editorKit.getInputAttributes());
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(3, text.length(), italic, false);
                    System.out.println("Text Pane: " + textPane.getText());
                }
                catch (BadLocationException exc)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        add(btnInsertTheText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        System.out.println("Text Pane: " + textPane.getText());
    }
}
```